# selecting entire hierarchy of rows from a self referencing table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains a self referencing foreign key.  Sort of like an employees table where each employee has reporting manager and it is hierarchical.  Here is an image of such a table.  In this table, the ParentId is a foreign key pointing to the Id column.

[image]

So, the question is I want to run a select query on this table with a given Id which should return all the parents that are hierarchically connected to the asking Id.  In other words, for example, if I ask for Id 14, it should return me Ids

```
[14 - 11 - q], 
[11 -  8 - m], 
[8  -  7 - j], 
[7  -  4 - h], 
[4  -  2 - e], 
[2  -  1 - c],
[1  -  1 - b].
```

Can somebody show me what the query should be in T-SQL?  Thanks.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Why isn't 15 "hierarchically connected" to 14?   They both have the same parent.   What result would you want if you ask for ID 8?

Comment: @EzLo So many duplicates to choose from, but sure I'll go with yours.  : )   However, if that one doesn't help, here are plenty more:   https://www.google.com/search?q=get+hierarchy+data+in+sql+server+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtqM3Lm7DbAhUMEqwKHY2iCLYQrQIINCgEMAA&biw=1920&bih=989

Comment: How come a node is parent of it self?

Comment: @TabAlleman : Not necessarily.  In this case, 14 and 15 are sort of siblings or at the same level.  To answer your 2nd question, if I ask for 8, I want 8, 7,4, 2 and 1 returned.

Comment: Ok, so you only want the "ancestors" of the requested ID, and not the "descendants" (nor "siblings").   That's not the same as asking for "all the rows that are hierarchically connected".   At least not to me, and not if you want to be perfectly clear.

Comment: 0 and 1 are parents of each other.  the typical answer is a recursive CTE would recursive forever

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza : think of this hierarchy as employees.  When the Parent is self, that means this id has no parent, in other words, the buck stops there.

Comment: @TabAlleman : Yes, you are correct!  Sorry, I should have been clearer.  I have edited my question.

Comment: @TabAlleman In this case a recursive go forever I dont think will be consider the same answer.

Comment: @Mazhar : No, they are not the parents of each other.  They are referencing themselves as parents.  They don't have parents.

Comment: @BabuMannavalappil if the don't have parents then the ParentId should be null

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza a very small, simple, modification prevents the recursion from going forever.   Anyone with a basic understanding of SQL can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this via a recursive CTE like below
<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/NLOWX40964)**</kbd>

```
  ; with rcte as 
(
   select id, parentid, name 
   from yourtable
   where id=8
   union all
   select t.id,t.parentid,t.name
   from yourtable t join rcte r
    on t.id=r.parentid and t.id<>t.parentid
   )

select * from rcte option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Comment: Thanks Dhruv.  When I run your query, I get an error message: The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: @BabuMannavalappil try the updated query... this should help

Comment: Thanks Dhruv.  Now, when I run the query, it goes into kind of a infinite loop.  I do get the hierarchy as I expect.  But when it comes to the top most parent for the asked id where id:1, parentid:1, name: b; then it starts repeating this row non-stop in the query result window.  I had to abort the query to stop it.

Comment: Are you sure that the query you  are running has the last line of rcte definition as `and t.id<>t.parentid`

Comment: the problem is with his data. He needs to change the ParentId of Ids 0 and 1 to Null otherwise the recursive CTE solution will be infinite

Comment: @Mazhar Actually no. See the demo I posted.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi : That is what I was missing; 'and t.id <> t.parentid'.  Once I added it, it is working fine.  Thanks.  I am marking your answer as accepted. Someone had downvoted you.  I can't seem to bring it to a positive number.  Only to '0'

Comment: @BabuMannavalappil Thanks.

Comment: @Mazhar : No Mazhar, I can't make that column nullable for other business reasons.  I also don't like to have nullable foreign keys.  So, rather than reshaping our heads to fit a hat, we should reshape or find a hat that fits the head.  That would be the right solution.  Thanks anyway for your input.  I appreciate it.

Comment: Do it like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6019e/8  That stop the recursion and give you the exact result you looking for

Comment: `t.id <> t.parent.id` doesnt work because doesnt give you the top node of the hierarchy. Is better `t.id <> r.id` mean doesnt join to itself